# Return hash with modified values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying this:

`{:id => 5, :foos => [1,2,3]}.each {|k,v| v.to_s}`

But that's returning this:

`{:id=>5, :foos=>[1, 2, 3]}`

I'd like to see this:

`{:id=>"5", :foos=>"[1, 2, 3]"}`

I've also tried variations of `Hash#collect` and `Hash#map`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000360):

```
{ :id => 5, :foos => [1, 2, 3] }.inject({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
  hash.merge key => value.inspect
end
```

which returns:

```
{ :foos => "[1, 2, 3]", :id => "5" }
```

or if you want it to be destructive:

```
hash = { :id => 5, :foos => [1, 2, 3] }
hash.each_key { |key| hash[key] = hash[key].inspect }
```

Comment: @rubiii, **note** in Ruby 1.9, `Array#to_s` produces the same result as `Array#inspect`. I don't know if this was true for previous versions.

Comment: @smotchkiss i just tried that using irb on 1.9.1-p378 and .. you're right :) didn't know that. for ruby 1.8.7 though [1,2,3].to_s just returns "123".

Answer (score 1):

Your stuff doesn't work because v.to_s doesn't modify v, so essentially the block doesn't do anything.

You could do it like this:

```
hash = {:id => 5, :foos => [1,2,3]}
hash.each_key { |k| hash[k] = hash[k].to_s }
```

If you don't want to modify the hash:

```
hash = {:id => 5, :foos => [1,2,3]}
new_hash = {}
hash.each_key { |k| new_hash[k] = hash[k].to_s }
```

Comment: @glebm, is there any method that does modify the hash?

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to do it without modifying the hash

Comment: @glebm, i **want** to modify the original hash. I don't need to avoid modifying it :)

Comment: the problem is that for an Array like [1, 2, 3], `to_s` returns "123", where `inspect` returns "[1, 2, 3]".

Comment: @smotchkkiss: The first method does modify the hash.

Comment: @sepp2k, I meant the original hash "literal" before setting it to a var. No worries though.