# Remove all html tags from attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a Project model and it has some text attributes, one is summary. I have some projects that have html tags in the summary and I want to convert that to plain text. I have this method that has a regex that will remove all html tags.

```
def strip_html_comments_on_data
  self.attributes.each{|key,value| value.to_s.gsub!(/(<[^>]+>|&nbsp;|\r|\n)/,"")}
end
```

I also have a before_save filter

```
before_save :strip_html_comments_on_data
```

The problem is that the html tags are still there after saving the project. What am I missing?

And, is there a really easy way to have that method called in all the models?

Thanks,

Nicolás Hock Isaza

Comment: I'm not a ruby user, but there doesn't seem to be any assignment occurring there. You're computing a string with those things stripped out, but not saving that anywhere.

Comment: @Yuliy ruby has mutable strings! (gsub! is the mutable form of gsub -- ick!) !!! (for good measure) !!! (and +1 for making me look at it harder)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

untested

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

def foo
  sanitized_output = sanitize(html_input)
end
```

where html_input is a string containing HTML tags.

**EDIT**

You can strip all tags by passing `:tags=>[]` as an option:

`plain_text = sanitize(html_input, :tags=>[])`

Although reading the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) I see there is a better method:

`plain_text = strip_tags(html_input)`

Then make it into a before filter per [smotchkiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184600/smotchkkiss) and you're good to go.

Comment: I don't want to sanitize it. I want to remove them. If I have <span> hello </span> I want to store just hello

Comment: Yeah! he strip_tags is the best way to go. Thank you!

Comment: strip_tags will not remove &nbsp and

Answer (score 11):

It would be better not to include view helpers in your model. Just use:

```
HTML::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize(text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the strip_tags()  text helper as mentioned by zetetic

Answer (score 1):

First, the issue here is that `Array#each` returns the input array regardless of the block contents. A couple people just went over `Array#each` with me in a question I asked: ["Return hash with modified values in Ruby"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572269/return-hash-with-modified-values-in-ruby).

Second, Aside from `Array#each` not really doing what you want it to here, I don't think you should be doing this anyway. Why would you need to run this method over *ALL* the model's attributes?

Finally, why not keep the HTML input from the users and just use the standard `h()` helper when outputting it?

```
# this will output as plain text
<%=h string_with_html %>
```

This is useful because you can view the database and see the unmodified data exactly as it was entered by the user (if needed). If you really must convert to plain text before saving the value, @zetetic's solution gets you started.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :sanitize_html

  protected
  def sanitize_html
    self.text = sanitize(text)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference Rails' sanitizer directly without using includes.

```
def text
  ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html).html_safe
end
```

NOTE: I appended .html_safe to make HTML entities like `&nbsp;` render correctly. Don't use this if there is a potential for malicious JavaScript injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `&nbsp;` along with html tags, nokogiri can be used

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

def foo
  sanitized_output = strip_tags(html_input)
  Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(sanitized_output)
end
```