# Sanitizing User Input with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a very simple CRUD app that takes user stories and stores them into a database so another fellow coder can organize them for a project we're both working on. However, I have come across a problem with sanitizing user input before it is saved into the database. I cannot call the sanitize() function from within the Story model to strip out all of the html/scripting. It requires me to do the following:

```
def sanitize_inputs
  self.name =  ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.name) unless self.name.nil?
  self.story = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.story) unless self.story.nil?
end
```

I want to validate that the user input has been sanitized and I am unsure of two things:
1) When should the user input validation take place? Before the data is saved is pretty obvious, I think, however, should I be processing this stuff in the Controller, before validation, or some other non-obvious area before I validate that the user input has no scripting/html tags?
2) Writing a unit test for this model, how would I verify that the scripting/html is removed besides comparing "This is a malicious code example" to the sanitize(example) output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but a reminder: rails 3 sanitizes user input by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to eliminate XSS vulnerabilities:

A.To filter the content before storing it in the DB (What you are trying to do). Here are 2 plugins that do this for you.

[xss_terminate](http://code.google.com/p/xssterminate/)

[acts_as_sanitiled](https://github.com/rymai/acts_as_sanitiled)

B.To filter the content when you display it (Rails 3 does it by default). You can either use the `h` function or use [rails_xss](http://github.com/nzkoz/rails_xss).

As with your second question, i think your unit test should only test that the sanitizing method is called, not the functionality itself(so a simple assertion on a basic example should do the trick). The sanitizing functions/plugins are already very well tested by default.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to acts_as_sanitized and xss_terminate. What this boils down too is that I need to use xss_terminate or roll my own, I guess.

Comment: I just found out the hard way that xss_terminate freaks out in Ruby 1.9 and returns all your database strings as "[]".  Another problem if you use HTML5libSanitize is that it relies on the extremely slow and no longer supported Ruby HTML5lib implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general consensus on sanitizing input is -- don't. Store the input as the user entered it and use the `sanitize` helper on output. (e.g, `<%=h @author.filthy_nasty_data %>`)

That said, you could always use the `strip_tags` helper as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576394/remove-all-html-tags-from-attributes-in-rails/2576491#2576491).

Comment: I disagree with the general consensus to not sanitize user input. Following this idea, we would not be scanning files on drives for viruses. I think proper defense in depth in this case is best effort sanitation of both input and output. Since this application will not have any special markup (no bb-code, etc), I see no reason not to just strip anything that looks suspicious from the input and not leave the possibility of a logic bomb sitting in my database waiting to be executed. 

There is always someone more clever than yourself, ya?

Comment: Never risk mangling user-input permanently. If you don't catch that "logic bomb" sitting in your database on output then you weren't going to catch it on input anyways.

Comment: The bad guy could insert code to exploit the insertion in the database, so you HAVE to sanitize it before insertion!

Comment: Of course you have to sanitize the strings for SQL or whatever if you are manually constructing database query strings. What zetetic and @coreyward are saying is that you don’t apply random other forms of mangling to the input itself and store the mangled form in the database. You don’t have to arbitrarily encode all foreign data before you store it in the database— that’s silly. Answer upvoted.

Comment: Generally disagree, if you have illegitimate input, it doesn't belong anywhere; your database or god forbid on your client side. There's just no reason to take the chance.